# Laravel Echo trigger event from front-end

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to build real-time game with Laravel and Echo.

It's multiplayer game, and after every step I need to update score for both players.

Obvious solution is to send request to back-end and on back-end side trigger event which updates score for all users on game's private channel.

Second solution is kind of weird in this case with Laravel Echo, triggering event from frond-end part like this:

```
Echo.connector.pusher.channels.channels.game_1.trigger(event, data)
```

It doesn't seem like best practice, right?

So first solution has disadvantage it sends request to back-end and waits for response, is it fast enough for game app?

The question is which solution is better in this case?

Comment: Hi, even this `event` for `game_1` is triggered, how would you update to your server? because triggered event is only broadcasted across clients, not server...

Answer (score 1):

I would use sockets and redis to subscribe to pub/sub events, this article reflects what I am saying.

https://medium.com/@adnanxteam/how-to-use-laravel-with-socket-io-e7c7565cc19d

Comment: yes you could send the request to backend, for example, to store the points to a database, I would use like 3 options:

1) When you receive the event on laravel echo, then ping to the backend.
2) On Frontend, when you receive the event, ping to the backend.
3) On laravel echo, when you receive the event, store it into a message queue engine, like rabbitmq, then process it on backend.

Comment: @Germanaz0 on your `options`, you mentioned about "ping the backend", do you mind to show a way how `Laravel Echo` could ping the backend with any data? Thanks.

Comment: @JustinMoh sure, just use fetch('backend-url/api/someAction') as a super abstract example, this will do an api call to the backend.

Comment: @Germanaz0 alright, that's an ajax call. I was thinking if you could _ping back_ with the existing web socket connection.